# Table Construction - With automatic line wrapping

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I build the following table in LaTeX with word wrapping? That is, according to the defined sheet size (A4) the text, automatically and in an adjusted way, is divided in line; without me having to add the separations manually.

Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[hbt!]
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\caption{Main modern references of the state of the art on the applied study of natural convection.}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{c|l}
\hline
REFERENCE                                                                                             & \multicolumn{1}{c}{DEVELOPED STUDIES}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
\citet{oosthuizen2001numerical}                                                                       & Numerical study of laminar natural convection heat transfer on wavy inclined surfaces (triangular and sinusoidal) of low amplitude, positioned parallel to the flow and with uniform surface temperature. From the analysis of the influence of the Grashof number, the amplitude and the dimensionless pitch of the waves, they concluded that the increase in the heat transfer rate is more influenced by the increase in the surface area due to the waves, than by the flow modifications that they cause. \\ \hline
\citet{kitamura2015}                                                                                  & Experimental study of natural convection on isothermal horizontal flat plates of different aspect ratios, obtaining empirical correlations of (Nu) ̅ x Ra for laminar, transitional and turbulent flow regimes. The correlations proved independent of the aspect ratio when using the equivalent diameter as the characteristic length in calculating (Nu) ̅ and Ra.                                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
\citet{wang2021reconstruction}                                                                        & Numerical-computational study that uses the deep neural network (DNN) technique to reconstruct – from training points of the flow and the heat transfer, obtained by CFD methods – the pressure fields, velocities and temperatures in natural convection (stable and unstable) in a closed environment.                                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \hline
\citet{yang2021simulating}                                                                            & Use of the smoothed particle hydrodynamics (SPH) method, in four different models, for numerical simulation of natural convection in a heated square cavity under high Rayleigh number conditions.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ \hline
\citet{wen2021laminar}                                                                                & Realization of direct numerical simulations for the study of flow by natural convection in a heated cubic cavity, with the investigation of the laminar-turbulent transition in the vertical boundary layer regions and its influence on the heat transfer rates.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ \hline
\citet{ren2021laminar}                                                                                & Numerical study with the compressible solver of the effect of random three-dimensional roughness elements on laminar natural convection in a heated square cavity.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ \hline
\citet{silva2021study}                                                                                & Numerical study of the influence of two different mesh configurations – non-uniform staggered and entirely uniform – on evaluating turbulent natural convection heat transfer rates over isothermal rectangular flat plates. Physical-experimental validation of numerical results obtained from literature results.                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\citet{junior2021physicala} and\\ \citet{junior2021physicalb}\end{tabular} & Numerical study of the main physical-numerical parameters that influence the prediction of natural convection heat transfer rates over isothermal flat plates, in turbulent and laminar regimes. Creation and validation of a physical-numerical methodology for studying this phenomenon in turbulent and laminar regimes.                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ \hline
\citet{verderio2022parametric}                                                                        & Numerical study - based on the geometry and operating conditions of real food ovens - of the influence of the geometric parameter height on heat transfer by radiation and convection (natural and forced) and on other flow parameters.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \hline
\citet{junior2021dimensionless}                                                                       & Analytical study to define a dimensionless formulation of transport equations and κ-ε and κ-ω SST turbulence models for the study of turbulent natural convection.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ \hline
\citet{junior2022experimental}                                                                        & Analytical study to define a physical-mathematical formulation and an experimental methodology for studying natural convection on flat plates and with waves.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \hline
\citet{ding2022natural}                                                                               & Experimental study of natural convection's influence on heat sinks' performance with phase change materials (PCMs).                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
\citet{chanakya2022effects}                                                                           & Numerical study of the effects of diffuse and collimated beam radiation on laminar natural convection flow in a cubic cavity with convective heating in the lower region.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\citet{kim2022pressure}                                                                               & Experimental investigation of air flow by natural convection between parallel vertical plates in asymmetric heating, with analysis of pressure behavior and heat transfer performance from variations in damper closing angle and thermal operating condition parameters.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\citet{bangian2022solution}                                                                           & Development of a methodology for inverse heat transfer problems by natural convection, validated by experimental results. Conclusion of vast application potential in real engineering systems, such as in the thermal management of electronic equipment.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\ \hline
\citet{weppe2022experimental}                                                                         & Experimental study of the thermal and dynamic behavior of flow by turbulent natural convection in a cubic cavity with a partially heated internal obstacle.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ \hline
\citet{gawas2022natural}                                                                              & Use of the multiple relaxation time Lattice Boltzmann method for the numerical study of the parameters domain tilt, thermal diffusion (isotropic and anisotropic) and Rayleigh number, on the natural convection heat transfer inside a square or rectangular cavity.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
\citet{junior2022natural}                                                                             & Numerical case study on the influence of several numerical parameters on physical-mathematical modeling and numerical solution of natural convection heat transfer problems on isothermal plates with square waves, in turbulent conditions of high Rayleigh number.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\label{Tab1}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Similar to some of the comments you received in your previous six questions: It helps you and others if you provide a better mwe. In addition, you did not accept a single answer in the past. I believe that people will be more willing to help if you give back.

Comment: Regarding the mwe: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Answer (score 2):

The package `tabbularx` provides a way to have `\linewidth` tables.

Please refer to this question:
[How to wrap around table row width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439111/how-to-wrap-around-table-row-width)

Another way is to use width specifier in the column definition:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790932/how-to-wrap-text-in-latex-tables

Finally, to stretch a table through multiple pages `longtable` packages exists:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896833/how-to-stretch-a-table-over-multiple-pages

Edit: to give a complete answer, here is an example of what could be made:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{5cm}|p{0.6\linewidth}|}
\centering
REFERENCE            &       \lipsum [1]               \\
\hline
hi  & \lipsum [1]    \\
hi  & \lipsum [1]    \\
hi  & \lipsum [1]    \\
hi  & \lipsum [1]    \\
hi  & \lipsum [1]    \\
hi  & \lipsum [1]    \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, anis.

However, I still haven't been able to make the table I need in LaTeX. I'll add the code if you can help me please.

I added the following packages: \usepackage{pdflscape}, \usepackage{tabularx} and \usepackage{longtable}.

Comment: Ok but a lot is missing in the code you posted. please provide the MWE (Minimal Working Example)

Comment: +1 Nice answer. You could also refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166743/automatic-line-break-in-tabular if you want.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's response.

I used this command \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|} to break lines inside the table.

However, my table is located on a horizontal border sheet. And with the command used, the table is the size of a vertical sheet.

How can I fix the table size to a standard A4 page in landscape position?

Answer (score 2):

- Please always provide complete small document, called MWE (Minimal Working Example). Information in its preamble can have strong influence on possible solution of your problem-
- How is your table related to "table-of-content" as you noted in question tag.
- Long table, which span several pages had not to be enclosed in table environment!
- Formatting/writing of your table can be done on several ways, like use packages `longtable`,  `xltabular`, ˙xlablex`etc. From them I would use`longtblr`of`tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs}
\DeclareMathOperator{\corr}{corr}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\SetTblrStyle{head}{font=\small}
\SetTblrStyle{foot}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Main modern references of the state of the art on the applied study of natural convection.},
  label = {Tab1}    ]{colspec = {@{} Q[l, wd=7.7em] X[j] @{}},
                      row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
                      rowsep  = 3pt,
                      rowhead = 1
                      }
    \toprule
REFERENCE
    &   DEVELOPED STUDIES   \\
    \midrule
\citet{oosthuizen2001numerical}
    & Numerical study of laminar natural convection heat transfer on wavy inclined surfaces (triangular and sinusoidal) of low amplitude, positioned parallel to the flow and with uniform surface temperature. From the analysis of the influence of the Grashof number, the amplitude and the dimensionless pitch of the waves, they concluded that the increase in the heat transfer rate is more influenced by the increase in the surface area due to the waves, than by the flow modifications that they cause.
                            \\
\citet{kitamura2015}
    & Experimental study of natural convection on isothermal horizontal flat plates of different aspect ratios, obtaining empirical correlations of $\corr(Nu,Ra)$ for laminar, transitional and turbulent flow regimes. The correlations proved independent of the aspect ratio when using the equivalent diameter as the characteristic length in calculating $\corr(Nu,Ra)$.
                            \\
\citet{wang2021reconstruction}
    & Numerical-computational study that uses the deep neural network (DNN) technique to reconstruct – from training points of the flow and the heat transfer, obtained by CFD methods – the pressure fields, velocities and temperatures in natural convection (stable and unstable) in a closed environment.
                            \\
\citet{yang2021simulating}                                                                            & Use of the smoothed particle hydrodynamics (SPH) method, in four different models, for numerical simulation of natural convection in a heated square cavity under high Rayleigh number conditions.
                            \\
\citet{wen2021laminar}                                                                                & Realization of direct numerical simulations for the study of flow by natural convection in a heated cubic cavity, with the investigation of the laminar-turbulent transition in the vertical boundary layer regions and its influence on the heat transfer rates.
                            \\
\citet{ren2021laminar}                                                                                & Numerical study with the compressible solver of the effect of random three-dimensional roughness elements on laminar natural convection in a heated square cavity.
                            \\
\citet{silva2021study}
    & Numerical study of the influence of two different mesh configurations – non-uniform staggered and entirely uniform – on evaluating turbulent natural convection heat transfer rates over isothermal rectangular flat plates. Physical-experimental validation of numerical results obtained from literature results.
                            \\
\citet{junior2021physicala} and \citet{junior2021physicalb}
    & Numerical study of the main physical-numerical parameters that influence the prediction of natural convection heat transfer rates over isothermal flat plates, in turbulent and laminar regimes. Creation and validation of a physical-numerical methodology for studying this phenomenon in turbulent and laminar regimes.
                        \\
\citet{verderio2022parametric}
    & Numerical study - based on the geometry and operating conditions of real food ovens - of the influence of the geometric parameter height on heat transfer by radiation and convection (natural and forced) and on other flow parameters.
                        \\
\citet{junior2021dimensionless}                                                                       & Analytical study to define a dimensionless formulation of transport equations and κ-ε and κ-ω SST turbulence models for the study of turbulent natural convection.
                        \\
\citet{junior2022experimental}                                                                        & Analytical study to define a physical-mathematical formulation and an experimental methodology for studying natural convection on flat plates and with waves.
                        \\
\citet{ding2022natural}                                                                               & Experimental study of natural convection's influence on heat sinks' performance with phase change materials (PCMs).
                        \\
\citet{chanakya2022effects}
    & Numerical study of the effects of diffuse and collimated beam radiation on laminar natural convection flow in a cubic cavity with convective heating in the lower region.
                        \\
\citet{kim2022pressure}                                                                               & Experimental investigation of air flow by natural convection between parallel vertical plates in asymmetric heating, with analysis of pressure behavior and heat transfer performance from variations in damper closing angle and thermal operating condition parameters.
                        \\
\citet{bangian2022solution}                                                                           & Development of a methodology for inverse heat transfer problems by natural convection, validated by experimental results. Conclusion of vast application potential in real engineering systems, such as in the thermal management of electronic equipment.
                        \\
\citet{weppe2022experimental}                                                                         & Experimental study of the thermal and dynamic behavior of flow by turbulent natural convection in a cubic cavity with a partially heated internal obstacle
                        \\
\citet{gawas2022natural}                                                                              & Use of the multiple relaxation time Lattice Boltzmann method for the numerical study of the parameters domain tilt, thermal diffusion (isotropic and anisotropic) and Rayleigh number, on the natural convection heat transfer inside a square or rectangular cavity.
                        \\
\citet{junior2022natural}                                                                             & Numerical case study on the influence of several numerical parameters on physical-mathematical modeling and numerical solution of natural convection heat transfer problems on isothermal plates with square waves, in turbulent conditions of high Rayleigh number.
                        \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

- Your table span three pages. The first two are:

[image]